# When shoud I use ssl_session_cache paramter in nginx ssl settings

Tags: nginx, ssl

What do I benefit from `ssl_session_cache` set in nginx.conf when I using https? See [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_session_cache).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When using SSL-Session-Cache, the performance of keep-alive connections over SSL might be enormously increased.

When the server does have it enabled, it is not necessary for the client to do a full SSL-handshake every request, thus saving time and cpu-resources.

You can read up more here: http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2011-ssl-session-reuse-rfc5077.html

And here is a benchmark: http://www.peterbe.com/plog/ssl_session_cache-ab

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why is it set to none by default?

Comment: The question was raised here: https://serverfault.com/questions/998053/why-is-the-ssl-session-cache-ssl-session-cache-disabled-by-default-in-nginx
It seems nobody knows. Maybe memory concerns?

Comment: lol, funny.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: Without ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m; Apple products cannot access the nginx server via SLL