# Why is the ssl session cache ( ssl_session_cache) disabled by default in nginx?

Tags: nginx, ssl, cache

In nginx, the ssl_session_cache directive has a default of 'none'. [ref](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_session_cache)

However, in the documentation for configuring HTTPS server, it's advised to turn on the ssl session cache, as it explains that SSL handshakes are cpu expensive. [ref](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html)

Further research on the topic supports the claim: [When shoud I use ssl_session_cache paramter in nginx ssl settings](https://serverfault.com/q/695258)

Therefore:

1. Why isn't it just turned on by default?
2. Does re-using SSL connections impose a security risk?

Answer (score 1):

I think the name parameter in shared:name:size needs to be unique per certificate. Multiple server blocks (different domains or subdomains) might or might not share certificates. Therefore, there isn't a one size fits all default value for the name parameter.

I would guess they could just default to not sharing the cache between server blocks, but I'm not an expert on this.